# Custom mesh from file is incomplete

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

i'm trying to create a mesh to represent specific countries on a globe. I'm taking lat/lon coordinates from a text file, converting them in x,y,z. Coordinates are stored into the `geoVertices` Vector3 array. The result is an incomplete mesh, on the upper part of the countries. See the picture below. The file is correct, i can render the mesh correctly with other tools.

This is the code i wrote so far. Do you know what the problem could be?

```
 public void drawCountry()
{
    MeshFilter meshFilter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

    int[] triangles = new int[3 * (geoVertices.Length - 2)];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < geoVertices.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        triangles[index++] = 0;
        triangles[index++] = i;
        triangles[index++] = i + 1;
    }

    mesh.vertices = geoVertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();

    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

    Material material = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Color"));
    material.color = new Color(1f, 0.5f, 0f, 0.5f);

    meshRenderer.material = material;

}
```

[image: Incomplete mesh spain and france]

Comment: I dont see you setting any uvs.

Comment: @BugFinder no i didn't. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Those triangles don't look quite right, notice your assigning vertex index 0 to ALL of them.  I'd suspect you want to use three vertices per triangle.
e.g

```
for (int i = 0; i < geoVertices.Length; i += 3)
{
    triangles[index++] = i + 0;
    triangles[index++] = i + 1;
    triangles[index++] = i + 2;
}
```

However, this example code ASSUMES that for touching triangles, each uses their own separate vertex for each touching corner- which may or may not be the case.  If this is not the case, you'll need more information to construct the triangles of the mesh.
edit: I also changed this example code to use a zero starting index for the `geoVerticies` collection.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to change the loop as you suggested but now i can only see a few points along the perimeter. How can i understand how to rearrange this part of code?

Comment: That result implies the triangles probably DO share vertices., but we cannot be sure HOW.  If you don't have this information the best we can do is GUESS at how to construct them.  You could TRY drawing a number at each vertex position, then manually draw lines until you have all the triangles, then hard-code them into the triangle array. But this will prove difficult, particularly for a large vertex list or highly curved mesh.  Are you sure there is no way to extract the triangle information from the same source you are getting the vertices from?  This would be the best way to go if you can.